# Can't downgrade from EMUI 9.1 with dload

Tags: huawei, emui, huawei-p20

I used the dload method to upgrade my dual-SIM Huawei P20 Lite (ANE-LX3 C605) with bootloader locked from EMUI 8.1 to 9.1. It is actually the first time I ever do something to this phone, so I am not completely sure how this works.

I think my phone was rebranded to C432 because the name of the firmware I downloaded is `Huawei P20 Lite ANE-LX1 ANE-L01 ANE-L21 hw eu Anne-L01 Anne-L21 9.1.0.132(C432E5R1P7T8) Firmware 9.0.0 r3 EMUI9.1.0 05014YWN 05014YXX.zip`.

EMUI 9.1 works like a charm, but I want to downgrade to EMUI 8 in order to have an earlier version of Google Play services.

I have download a few different firmware from androidhost.ru:

1. Huawei P20 Lite ANE-LX3 ANE-L23 claro la Anne-L23 8.0.0.152(C605) Firmware 8.0.0 r1 EMUI8.0 05015ATQ
2. Huawei P20 Lite ANE-LX1 ANE-L21 hw eu Anne-L21 8.0.0.150(C432) Firmware 8.0.0 r1 EMUI8.0 05014YWN
3. Huawei P20 Lite ANE-LX1 ANE-L21 hw eu HLRCF Anne-L21 8.0.0.180(C432) Firmware 8.0.0 r1 EMUI8.0 05014YXX

With 1. and 3. it says "Software install failed! Get help from www.emui.com"
With 2. it says that the software package is not compatible with the current version .

I have attached a couple of screenshots with info on the version and build number as seen currently.

[image: Project menu]
[image: About]

Any help with this matter would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Downgrade because of Google Play Service!? Those services will automatically update once you managed the downgrade.

Comment: Right. So I will uninstall the updates and keep it from updating

Comment: how will you prevent google services from updating? this is only possible with app `cn.wq.disableservice` (and afaik requires root permissions)

Comment: Note: this question was also posted on [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-cant-downgrade-from-emui-9-1-with-dload.3941766/).

Answer (score 0):

I read about that, you need to downgrade one by one. Emui 9.1 To Emui 9.0, then Emui 9.0 to Emui 8.0.

Comment: Hello. This might actually be true, but could you mention the link where you read about this solution?